# JavaScript App using UDP sockets - NodeJS & SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to develop a JavaScript application which should be able to communicate though UDP sockets with other 3rd-party applications and represent some data via a local browser window.

As far as I know I should use NodeJS for the UDP socket connectivity and I've already test its sample UDPserver.js example which seems to work great.

My problem now is how can I pass the data received from the UDPserver (running locally on NodeJS console) to my main application, which would be running on the browser. I've read that I have to use Socket.IO to achieve this realtime connection.

So, its something like having a client app and a server app running simultaneously on the same machine? How exactly socketIO would connect the two parts? Should I use WebSockets to bridge my App with NodeJS or sth?

```
  |  JQUERY JS  |         |  NODE.JS |                     |      C++     | 
  |             |   [?]   |          |    [UDP SOCKETS]    |              |
  |LOCAL WEB APP| <=====> |UDP SERVER| <-----------------> |3RD-PARTY APPS| 
  |   (local)   |         |  (local) |                     |   (network)  |
```

Can someone clear it up a bit for me? It should be something relatively easy, but I'm new to this..

Comment: you could directly stream the udp packet buffers to websocket binary, but it will not give you a good result. Isn't TCP an option? there are some nice bridges TCP<->websocket to use.

Comment: ye, I've checked some of those, like websockify. It works nicely, but unfortunately the third-part apps, which I want to connect to, are using UDP sockets exclusively..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a normal browser does not give JavaScript direct access to sockets, you can't accomplish this with just a webpage.  You are on the right track with using a node intermediary and connecting the browser via websockets.

However, your application might be best suited to [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), which integrates a Chromium browser with node.js in the same package.  This means your webpage code can use node APIs like UDP sockets directly.

Comment: Ok, at last I'm pretty sure `Node-WebKit` would do the job much simplier for me! Thanks Josh, answer granted!

Answer (score 4):

Your browser cannot communicate over UDP.  (Outside of WebRTC anyway.)

WebSockets are not real network sockets.  They are a layer of abstraction over a TCP connection that is first set up via an HTTP request.

Socket.IO is another layer of abstraction over that which provides WebSocket-like functionality, as well as RPC, over several transports including WebSockets, long-polling JSON, etc.